# How to exclude one child in XPath/CSS locator

Tags: html, xpath, css-selectors

Is there any way to get div's inner text except 'by '?

```
<div class="name">
    "by "
    <em>Some Author</em>
    ", "
    <em>Another Author</em>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's pretty strange about your HTML is the quotes and the whitespace between the "Some Author" `<em>` and the comma.  I assume you mean this instead:

```
<div class="name">
  by <em>Some Author</em>, <em>Another Author</em>
</div>
```

With XPath, you could fetch the nodes with a query like this:

```
//*[@class='name']/node()[position()>1]
```

If we're talking about a browser environment and you want a single string, not just a collection of nodes, you could do:

```
document.querySelector('div.name').textContent.replace(/^\s*by\s*/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Jquery like this... but it'll remove the `","` too... 
Check it out:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var name = $('div').children('em');
  $('div').html(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="name">
    "by "
    <em>Some Author</em>
    ", "
    <em>Another Author</em>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the expression:

```
//em/text()
```

Output:

```
    'Some Author'
    'Another Author'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try below XPath to get *all descendant text nodes, except the first one*:

```
(//div//text())[position() > 1]
```